# Mapping and filtering a nested object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find all objects that contain filter with the `Name` of `Industry` and the `Value` of `Tech`. Here's my object:

```
const obj = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Video Games",
    "Labels": [{
        "Name": "Industry",
        "Value": "TMT"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Analyst",
        "Value": "Jen Cardage"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Software",
    "Labels": [],    
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Internet",
    "Labels": [{
        "Name": "Industry",
        "Value": "Tech"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Analyst",
        "Value": "Mike Smith"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This gets me objects with non-empty `Labels`, in this case, `Id`s `1` and `3`.

```
const containsLabels = obj.filter(({Labels}) => Labels.length > 0);
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to chain another `map` and/or `filter` onto `containsLabels` to map over and check against the `Name`s and `Value` contained  therein.

How can I get the object with `Id: 3` out of `containsLabels`? My running code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wn04mshu/12/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Labels is an array (as is obj), so running `find()` nested should do the trick:

```js
const containsLabels = obj.filter(({ Labels }) => 
  Labels.find(({ Name, Value }) => Name === 'Industry' && Value === 'Tech')
);
```

I [forked your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YuanHaoChiang/zmu2dsg3/1/) with the working version.

It is unnecessary to filter for objects where `Label.length > 0`, because `find()` will `return null` when running on an empty array.

If `Labels` is not always present, the above code would throw an error. Instead, you can use the **optional chaining operator** (`?.`), or the traditional `&&`:

```js
const containsLabels = obj.filter(({ Labels }) => 
  Labels?.find(({ Name, Value }) => Name === 'Industry' && Value === 'Tech')
);

// Or...
const containsLabels = obj.filter(({ Labels }) => 
  Labels && Labels.find(({ Name, Value }) => Name === 'Industry' && Value === 'Tech')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do `find` directly in the first `filter`

```
const containsLabels = obj.filter(({ Labels }) =>
  Labels.find(Label => Label.Value === 'Tech')
)

console.log(containsLabels)
```

**Runnable example**

```js
const obj = [
  {
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'Video Games',
    Labels: [
      {
        Name: 'Industry',
        Value: 'TMT'
      },
      {
        Name: 'Analyst',
        Value: 'Jen Cardage'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    Name: 'Software',
    Labels: []
  },
  {
    Id: 3,
    Name: 'Internet',
    Labels: [
      {
        Name: 'Industry',
        Value: 'Tech'
      },
      {
        Name: 'Analyst',
        Value: 'Mike Smith'
      }
    ]
  }
]

const containsLabels = obj.filter(({ Labels }) =>
  Labels.find(Label => Label.Value === 'Tech')
)

console.log(containsLabels)
```

Or just continue chaining if you want, because `filter` returns the new array of the same elements but filtered

```
const containsLabels = obj
  .filter(({ Labels }) => Labels.length > 0)
  .filter(({ Labels }) => Labels.find(Label => Label.Value === 'Tech'))
```